# Struct that owns some data and a reference to the data

Tags: rust, object-lifetime, borrow-checker

Construction of an object allocates data needed for lifetime of that object, but also creates another object that needs to keep references to the data:

```
pub fn new() -> Obj {
    let data = compute();

    Obj {
        original: data,
        processed: AnotherObj {
            reference: &data
        }
    }
}
```

Is it possible to express this in Rust's terms?

Here I'd like `Obj`, `AnotherObj` and `data` to have the same lifetime, and of course outlive the `new()` call.

Comment: Both the question and the accepted answer here are more clear than in the "duplicate".

Answer (score 21, accepted):

A raw design of the structs based on your requirements might look like this:

```rust
struct AnotherObj<'a> {
    original: &'a Vec<i8>, // Let's agree on Vec<i8> as your "data" type.
}

struct Obj<'a> {
    original: Vec<i8>,         // <-------------------+
    processed: AnotherObj<'a>, // should point here --+
}
```

However it's very tricky to get working (personally, I wasn't able to) because you want the `'a` in `AnotherObj<'a>` to be the lifetime of `original`. However you must supply a lifetime to `Obj<'a>` and thus you would have to specify `Obj<'tbc>` where `'tbc` is the lifetime of the `Obj` to be created.

I suggest the following alternatives:

#### 1. Make AnotherObj actually *own* the original

Why not? `Obj` will own `AnotherObj`, so it can still have access to `original` as a nested child:

```rust
pub struct AnotherObj {
    original: Vec<i8>,
}

pub struct Obj {
    processed: AnotherObj,
}

pub fn new() -> Obj {
    let data = vec![1,2,3];

    Obj {
        processed: AnotherObj {
            original: data,
            // ...
        }
    }
}

// access as obj.processed.original, you can even create a getter `fn original(&self)`
```

#### 2. Shared pointer design

Straightforward use of refcounted pointers:

```rust
use std::rc::Rc;

pub struct AnotherObj {
    original: Rc<Vec<i8>>,
}

pub struct Obj {
    original: Rc<Vec<i8>>,
    processed: AnotherObj,
}

pub fn new() -> Obj {
    let data = Rc::new(vec![1,2,3]);

    Obj {
        original: data.clone(),
        processed: AnotherObj {
            original: data.clone(),
        }
    }
}
```

#### 3. With raw pointers

Options 1. and 2. will bring you the peace of mind of the safe Rust gods, therefore I don't recommend this third option. I still post it here for completeness. Note: it compiles, but I never tested it at runtime, so it may bite. There's only safe code below but you'll have to go in `unsafe` land when you want to dereference the raw pointer.

```rust
use std::ptr;

pub struct AnotherObj {
    original: *mut Vec<i8>,
}

pub struct Obj {
    original: Vec<i8>,
    processed: AnotherObj,
}

pub fn new() -> Obj {
    let data = vec![1,2,3];

    let mut obj = Obj {
        original: data,
        processed: AnotherObj {
            original: ptr::null_mut(),
        }
    };
    obj.processed.original = &mut obj.original as *mut Vec<i8>;

    obj
}
```

Comment: The raw pointers option falls apart as soon as you move the `Obj`. In your code sample, that's as soon as you return the `Obj` from `new`. With optimizations, `new` might actually initialize an `Obj` that was allocated by the caller, which would give you the illusion that it works, but I haven't tested this. You'd have to box the `Obj` to give it a fixed address, but Rust wouldn't prevent you from moving the `Obj` out of the box.