# Rust how to wrap container to support Iterator in custom struct

Tags: rust, iterator, containers

What I'd like to be able to do is rely on existing containers to handle however they contain multiple items, and use their existing iterator to iterate over the container. I am aware of the existing questions:

- [how-to-initialize-struct-fields-which-reference-each-other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25269597/how-to-initialize-struct-fields-which-reference-each-other)
- [how-to-store-hashmap-and-its-values-iterator-in-the-same-struct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31988530/how-to-store-hashmap-and-its-values-iterator-in-the-same-struct)
- [struct-that-owns-some-data-and-a-reference-to-the-data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30823880/struct-that-owns-some-data-and-a-reference-to-the-data)

So, I've gathered that it's not possible in Rust to keep a reference to the container and its iterator in a custom struct, but I'm looking for a solution that would allow my custom struct to implement `Iterator` to iterate over the container in my custom struct.

I've created the simplest example of what I'm trying to do:

- [HashMap playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=b4592ec8baee0944230b966e682fee21) (edit: [@Stargateur solution](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=7928a9b07ac0e509507dad21da08d09a))
- [Vec playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=e531e99bf75252c316ed42433bd17242) (edit: [possible solution](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=fd9a1c76c696ad2d5f0adcfb340ed4cb))

How can I modify `UserStore` to support iteration? Or is this just not possible in Rust and need to essentially reimplement all the container functionality in `UserStore` itself?

Comment: You'll find looking at the standard collections that the data structure itself does not implement `Iterator`, they use a separate type. If you follow that pattern for a custom wrapper, the problem in the three linked Q&As does not appear.

Comment: I read twice the question but it still unclear to me, what do you want ? Don't tell what you tried, tell me what you want do to. Why do you want a wrapper iterator thing.

Comment: @Stargateur I want `UserStore` to use `HashMap` but still support iterating through the `HashMap`'s items. e.g. `for user in user_store { println!("{user}"); }`

Comment: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=7928a9b07ac0e509507dad21da08d09a, thus hashmap iterator is unordered so your assert are wrong.

Comment: Ugh, I knew there had to be a simple solution. Thanks @Stargateur